# Error durante INSERT MySQL, pero no se muestra el error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo un codigo php que deberia insertarme en la BD pero no inserta,tengo PDO,try-catch,mostrar errores de php pero nada funciona,cambie de xampp a wampp y aun asi no puedo ver cual es el error,todo el codigo tanto del formulario como del servidor esta bien

**este es el codigo php:**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);

ob_start();
session_start();
include("inc/config.php");
include("inc/funciones.php");

$mensaje_error='';

if(isset($_POST['form_añadir_vehiculo'])) {
        
    // Validar que ningún campo obligatorio esté vacío
    if(empty($_POST['foto_tarjeta_propiedad_frontal']) ||  empty($_POST['foto_tarjeta_propiedad_posterior']) || empty($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['modelo']) || empty($_POST['tipo']) || empty($_POST['chasis']) || empty($_POST['motor']) || empty($_POST['placa']) || empty($_POST['foto'])) {
        $mensaje_error = 'Ninguno de los datos pueden estar vacios!<br>';
    } else {
        
        // Limpiar los datos para evitar inyecciones SQL
        $nombre_limpiado = limpiar_cadena($_POST['nombre']);
        $modelo_limpiado = limpiar_cadena($_POST['modelo']);
        $tipo_limpiado = limpiar_cadena($_POST['tipo']);    
        $chasis_limpiado = limpiar_cadena($_POST['chasis']);
        $motor_limpiado = limpiar_cadena($_POST['motor']);
        $placa_limpiada = limpiar_cadena($_POST['placa']);    
        
        // Asignar los datos limpios a las variables correspondientes
        $nombre = $nombre_limpiado;
        $modelo = $modelo_limpiado;
        $tipo = $tipo_limpiado;
        $chasis = $chasis_limpiado;
        $motor = $motor_limpiado;
        $placa = $placa_limpiada;
        
        // Asignar el ID del conductor asignado
        $conductor_asignado = $_POST['conductor_asignado'];
        
        // Iniciar una transacción
        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        try {
            // Preparar la consulta INSERT
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO vehiculos (id_conductor, foto_tarjeta_propiedad_frontal_vehiculo, foto_tarjeta_propiedad_posterior_vehiculo, nombre_vehiculo, modelo_vehiculo, tipo_vehiculo, chasis_vehiculo, motor_vehiculo, placa_vehiculo, foto_vehiculo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            
            // Inicializar un array para almacenar los nombres de los archivos
            $nombres_archivos = [];

            // Procesar cada archivo subido
            foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
                $archivo = 'imagenes/' . basename($value['name']);
                $tipoArchivo = strtolower(pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                // Validar que el archivo es una imagen
                $check = getimagesize($value['tmp_name']);
                if($check !== false) {
                    // Intentar subir el archivo
                    if (move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], $archivo)) {
                    //if (copy($value['tmp_name'], $archivo)) { 
                        // Almacenar el nombre del archivo en el array
                        $nombres_archivos[$key] = basename($value['name']);
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception("Hubo un error subiendo la imagen.");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("El archivo no es una imagen.");
                }
            }

            // Ejecutar la consulta con un array de valores
            $statement->execute(array(
                $conductor_asignado,
                $nombres_archivos['foto_tarjeta_propiedad_frontal'],
                $nombres_archivos['foto_tarjeta_propiedad_posterior'],
                $nombre,
                $modelo,
                $tipo,
                $chasis,
                $motor,
                $placa,
                $nombres_archivos['foto_vehiculo']
            ));

            // Confirmar la transacción
            $pdo->commit();

            echo "Los datos del vehículo han sido insertados correctamente.";
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            // Si hay un error, revertir la transacción
            $pdo->rollBack();
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }
    
}


?>
```

**y este es mi codigo del formulario:**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <?php 
                            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_conductor, nombre_conductor FROM conductores WHERE id_vehiculo IS NULL");
                            $statement->execute();
                            $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                            ?>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label">Asignar un conductor a este vehiculo</label>
                                <select class="form-select" name="conductor_asignado" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
                                <?php while($row = $statement->fetch()): ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row->id_conductor; ?>"><?php echo $row->nombre_conductor; ?></option>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label custom-file-input">Foto Tarjeta Propiedad Vehiculo(FRONTAL)</label>
                                <input name="foto_tarjeta_propiedad_frontal" class="form-control" type="file">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label custom-file-input">Foto Tarjeta Propiedad Vehiculo(POSTERIOR)</label>
                                <input name="foto_tarjeta_propiedad_posterior" class="form-control" type="file">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label">Nombre Vehiculo</label>
                                <input name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Aqui el Nombre del Vehiculo..">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label">Modelo Vehiculo</label>
                                <input name="modelo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Aqui el Modelo del Vehiculo..">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label">Tipo Vehiculo</label>
                                <input name="tipo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Aqui el Tipo del Vehiculo..">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label">Chasis Vehiculo</label>
                                <input name="chasis" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Aqui el Chasis del Vehiculo..">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label">Motor Vehiculo</label>
                                <input name="motor" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Aqui el Motor del Vehiculo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label">Placa Vehiculo</label>
                                <input name="placa" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Aqui la Placa del Vehiculo..">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-label custom-file-input">Foto Vehiculo</label>
                                <input name="foto" class="form-control" type="file">
                            </div>
                            <button name="form_añadir_vehiculo" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
                        </form>
```

**esta es la BD:**

[image: BD imagen aqui click para ver]

ya probe con las 2 funciones para subir archibos,tanto la funcion

> COPY

como la funcion

> MOVE_UPLOAD_FILE y aun asi no logro identificar el error,tambien esta la tabla conductores en la cual existe un condcutor libre,pero al final nada.

Comment: Siempre revisa primero la [condición de error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php), en tu caso `$value['error']`.

Answer (score 2):

El primer problema está en el `if` que valida si los campos están vacíos.
Si haces un `var_dump($_POST)` verás que los campos donde se agregaron imágenes no vienen en esa superglobal. Ellas vienen en `$_FILES`.

El código no muestra ningún error porque el mismo se está asignando a una variable: `$mensaje_error = 'Ninguno de los datos pueden estar vacios!<br>';` pero no se imprime en ningún lado (al menos en la porción de código suministrado) y por eso no lo ves. Si le pones un `echo` aparecerá.

Entonces para corregir esa parte:

```php
if(empty($_FILES['foto_tarjeta_propiedad_frontal']) ||  
empty($_FILES['foto_tarjeta_propiedad_posterior']) || 
empty($_POST['nombre']) || 
empty($_POST['modelo']) || 
empty($_POST['tipo']) || 
empty($_POST['chasis']) || 
empty($_POST['motor']) || 
empty($_POST['placa']) || 
empty($_FILES['foto'])) {
    // ERROR: Ninguno de los datos pueden estar vacios!
} else {
    // ...
}
```

El siguiente problema está en la línea de `$statement->execute(...)`, hay un índice incorrecto.
Cambiar `$nombres_archivos['foto_vehiculo']` por `$nombres_archivos['foto']`

---

[*] Observo una potencial [referencia circular](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+circular+reference) (o cíclica) entre esas 2 tablas:

```txt
conductor (id_conductor) -> id_vehiculo
vehiculos (id_vehiculo) -> id_conductor
```

Suponiendo que la tabla conductores es la entidad principal, entonces no es necesario tener un `id_vehiculo`. Si quieres saber qué conductor no tiene asignado vehículo, haces un `SELECT ... JOIN` entre las 2 tablas.
Incluso en un modelo más avanzado, se puede tener una tercera tabla de cruce entre las 2 primeras, que se encargaría de manejar la asignación, y también podría conservar el histórico de las asignaciones en el tiempo.